# delete the last items of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table in the database and I get a JSON from it.

when I decode the results I have an array like this :

```
array("1" => "Jason" ,
      "2" => "Jimmy" ,
      "3" => "Christopher" , 
      "4" => "Bruce" , 
      "5" => "james" , 
      "6" => "Mike" ,
      "7" => "Brad" );
```

how can I remove the last items from the database when I add a new one.

for example :

when I add `Walter` and `Kevin`, the code removes the `Brad` and `Mike` from DB:

```
array("1" => "Walter" ,
      "2" => "Kevin" ,
      "3" => "Jason" ,
      "4" => "Jimmy" ,
      "5" => "Christopher" , 
      "6" => "Bruce" , 
      "7" => "james"  );
```

Comment: and what about the key 6,7?

Comment: Read about PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). All the answers are there.

Comment: How about the code you're using for the DB? All you described is what you want, not how you got here. See [mcve]

Comment: It's a XY problem.

Comment: Is the JSON generated from a set of records or is it stored as text in a single record? Without knowing the structure of the data in the database it's not really possible to provide an acceptable answer.

Comment: that's about the array , when i add new items to DB I want the array code remove the last items and update the db and array just has 7 value

Comment: Again, what code? All you're giving is is the **output**. Without the code that generates the array in the first place, we're only guessing

Comment: The answers provided are related to the title of your question but not the issue you want to resolve. You tagged the question as **mysql**, yet all you have provided is a PHP array declaration. You seem to want to update a database but have provided no information regarding the structure of the database table. People would like to help you but need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use array_shift / array_unshift, but since the logic seems upside down, you could use something like

```
     <?php


    $apparentDB = array("1" => "Jason" ,
          "2" => "Jimmy" ,
          "3" => "Christopher" , 
          "4" => "Bruce" , 
          "5" => "james" , 
          "6" => "Mike" ,
          "7" => "Brad" );
  /*  You can add it one by one
    $addName = "Walter";
    $apparentDB = addName($addName, $apparentDB);
    $addSecondName = "Kevin";
    $apparentDB = addName($addSecondName, $apparentDB);
*/

// Or you can also modify to work on an array of new names
    $newNames = array("Walter", "Kevin");
    foreach($newNames as $newName) {
        $apparentDB = addName($newName, $apparentDB);
    }
    var_dump($apparentDB);

    function addName($nameToAdd, $apparentDB) {

        for ($i = count($apparentDB); $i > 1; $i--) {
            $apparentDB["".$i] = $apparentDB["".($i-1)];
        }

        $apparentDB["1"] = $nameToAdd;

        //var_dump($apparentDB);
        return $apparentDB;
    }
```

*You can test it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ *

Comment: that's work but when i insert two value it shows two array

Comment: Maybe this changed will help

Answer (score 0):

```
       $a=  array("1" => "Jason" ,
              "2" => "Jimmy" ,
              "3" => "Christopher" , 
              "4" => "Bruce" , 
              "5" => "james" , 
              "6" => "Mike" ,
              "7" => "Brad" );
      $b = array_pop($a) ;
var_dump ($a) ; // this all item without Brad ,
$b // This is Brad ;
```

to add element to array

```
array_push($a ,"New Name");
```

Comment: He mentioned a DB so this is probably not what he's trying to do.

Comment: i see he need to change element from array :) , so i write about array as he ask array i think what he want to do actually to add status=>'done' for json but in complicated way :)